# IUSR File Upload Permissions

Tags: php, iis, permissions

I'm trying to setup a PHP site and having a small issue with IIS and IUSR permissions. The problem is that when I try to upload images through my CMS it tells me that I don't have the necessary write permissions. However, it will upload a thumbnail of my photo to a folder /files. I know that it is ultimately supposed to store the file in /files/pages but the image is never moved there. Now, my files/ folder does inherit permissions from my wwwroot folder, at this moment IUSR as Full Control (I'd like to not have it like this). IUSR has Full Contorl on every folder, including wwwroot, as well as Full Share privileges. When I check Effective Access in Security Advanced Settings, it shows that IUSR has all the privileges. To make it even stranger, when I set the site to Connect As my personal account (I'm an administrator), everything works fine. I've tried to mimic permissions as best as I could figure but still nothing. Also my tmp_upd_dir in PHP is Windows/temp which IUSR has Modify permissions on as well. I'm hoping somebody has had this struggle and somehow got theirs to work. Any thoughts are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give modify permissions to [MachineName]\IIS_IUSRS and see if that works